# Xcode 11 Error: Multiple Commands produce... when trying to archive with new build system

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

I try to archive my app with the new Build System in Xcode. I tried to update the pods, but this didn't help. I don't see whats going wrong with this.

This is the error I get when trying to Archive.

```
Multiple commands produce '/Users/damianvandekauter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Peral-gccnzsgqesdkhpgldsjorooqirpb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Peral/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Parse.bundle':
1) Target 'Parse-iOS12.0-Parse' has create directory command with output '/Users/damianvandekauter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Peral-gccnzsgqesdkhpgldsjorooqirpb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Peral/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Parse.bundle'
2) Target 'Parse-iOS9.0-Parse' has create directory command with output '/Users/damianvandekauter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Peral-gccnzsgqesdkhpgldsjorooqirpb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Peral/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Parse.bundle'
```

I know I can go back to the legacy build system, but I would prefer using the new and faster build system. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Removing duplicate font files in Copy Bundle Resources worked for me.

The problem seems to be caused by the new autolinking feature in React Native 0.60 - the line use_native_modules! in ios/Podfile means when you do pod install, any pods found in node_modules are automatically linked. This means that links to all font files are added to [CP] Copy Pods Resources when you do pod install.

If you previously installed react-native-vector-icons manually by adding the font files to Copy Bundle Resources, you then get a "Multiple commands produce..." fatal build error.

So to fix the problem, just remove the font files from Copy Bundle Resources, so that they are only in [CP] Copy Pods Resources.

Copy Bundle Resources can be found under the Build Phases` tab in the target in your project

the error will be solved